# App Rejected due to In App Purchase

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

Apple reject my application due to below reason:

2.2 Binary Rejected 
Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad and iPhone running iOS

From Apple
2. 1 Performance: App Completeness
3. 1.1 Business: Payments - In-App Purchase
Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad and iPhone running iOS 11.3.1 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network. Specifically no action occurs when we attempt to purchase your declared In-App Purchases.

￼￼Please see attached screenshots for details.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please run your app on a device to identify any issues, then revise and resubmit your app for review.

If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to this message in Resolution Center to provide information on how these features were intended to work.

For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce the issue. For updates, install the new version as an update to the previous version, then follow the steps to reproduce the issue.

Resources

For information about testing your app and preparing it for review, please see Technical Note TN2431: App Testing Guide.

For a networking overview, please review About Networking. For a more specific overview of App Review’s IPv6 requirements, please review the IPv6 and App Review discussion on the Apple Developer Forum.

Guideline 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase

We also found that your app offers in-app purchases that can be restored but does not include a "Restore Purchases" feature to allow users to restore the previously purchased in-app purchases, as specified in the "Restoring Purchase Products" section of the In-App Purchase Programming Guide:

"Users restore transactions to maintain access to content they've already purchased. For example, when they upgrade to a new phone, they don't lose all of the items they purchased on the old phone. Include some mechanism in your app to let the user restore their purchases, such as a Restore Purchases button."

To restore previously purchased in-app purchase products, it would be appropriate to provide a "Restore" button and initiate the restore process when the "Restore" button is tapped by the user.

Request a phone call from App Review

At your request, we can arrange for an Apple Representative to call you within the next three to five business days to discuss your App Review issue.

Request a call to discuss your app’s review.
/// My openions:

I have tested complete application with live enviorenment and IAP working fine with restoring functionality.

Also in my feature section:

[image]

Please suggest:

Thanks

Comment: Have you sent it out to others on Testflight. Can they also replicate the functionality? Also if you click on "Unlock Levels" does it have any actions that need to be finished to put the IAP live?

Comment: yes i have put it on testflight and other developer test it. It is working fine. Also when I click on "Unlock Levels" it is showing red warning on language section, but previouslu everything working fine,  from today it is showing lie this error.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the errors on the language section?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ewssusytdz9cxh8/Screen%20Shot%202018-05-08%20at%207.36.20%20PM.png?dl=0
Pls check it

Comment: Any one has answer for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add any character in display name then save it. Then remove that word and save it.
It will change automatically waiting for review.

Answer (score 0):

On the next day of my question I just edit the discription of in app purchase and save it. It removed the error and show status waiting for review. 
See the screen shot.

[image]